# Using jQuery, how I can get the file portion of the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How I can get the URL portion of an URL using jQuery?

I have this URL: `http://127.0.0.1/deposito/site/main/lojas.php`. How I can get `lojas.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
var pathParts = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var file = pathParts[pathParts.length - 1];
alert(file);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use JavaScript and a regex to retrieve the file name like this:

```
function GetFilename(url){
   if (url){
      var m = url.toString().match(/.*\/(.+?)\./);
      if (m && m.length > 1){
         return m[1];
      }
   }
   return "";
}
```

The above solution is more comprehensive, but something as simple as this would work in the majority of cases:

```
var filename = url.match(/.*\/(.+?)\./);
```

If you need to use jQuery, you can use the `jQuery-URL-Parser` plugin:

```
var file = $.url.attr("file");
```

Here's a link to the plugin:
https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

Answer (score 0):

If it's the document's current URL, you can "split-pop" `document.location.pathname`:

```
alert(document.location.pathname.split("/").pop());
//-> "lojas.php"
```

Otherwise, if you have the URL in a string you will need to remove any hash or query strings:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1/deposito/site/main/lojas.php"

alert(url.replace(/(?:\?|#).+/, "").split("/").pop());
//-> "lojas.php"
```